# Delphi Xe2 inserting records into table based on values from another table

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have the following code that i use to update a table in a database this code used to work in bds 2006 using zeosdblib query components, but now it does not work in delphi xe2. Can anyone please show me where i am going wrong. Thank You

```
procedure TGoodsReceivedForm.btnCategorizeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TempCatTotal : Extended;
  nCatogory : string;
begin
TempCatTotal := 0;
zroqryExpcat.Open;
with zroqryExpcat do
begin
 first;
while not Eof do
begin
 zqrySumCategory.Close;
 zqrySumCategory.SQL.Clear;
 zqrySumCategory.SQL.Add('select costcategory,packcost,sum(qty)*packcost as pamount');
 zqrySumCategory.SQL.Add('from pitems');
 zqrySumCategory.SQL.Add('where costcategory=:costcategory and orderno=:orderno');
 zqrySumCategory.SQL.Add('group by costcategory,packcost');
 zqrySumCategory.Params[0].AsString := zroqryExpcat.FieldByName('Description').Value;
 zqrySumCategory.Params[1].AsString := NewPurchaseOrderForm.OrderNumber.Caption ;
 zqrySumCategory.Open;
 zqrySumCategory.First;
 TempCatTotal := 0;
 while not zqrySumCategory.eof do
 begin
  TempCatTotal := TempCatTotal+zqrySumCategory.FieldByName('pamount').AsFloat;
  zqrySumCategory.Next;
 end;
 if TempCatTotal > 0 then
 begin
  zqryInsertExpense.Close;
  zqryInsertExpense.Params[0].AsString := NewPurchaseOrderForm.OrderNumber.Caption ;
  zqryInsertExpense.Params[1].AsString := zqrySumCategory.Params[0].AsString ;
  zqryInsertExpense.Params[2].AsCurrency := TempCatTotal;
  zqryInsertExpense.Params[3].Asinteger := zroqryExpcat.FieldByName('gl_account_no').Value;
  zqryInsertExpense.Params[4].AsDate := ReceivedDate.Date;
  zqryInsertExpense.ExecSQL;
  zqryInsertExpense.Close;
end;
next;
end;
end;
  zqryListExpenseCat.Close;
  zqryListExpenseCat.Params[0].Value := NewPurchaseOrderForm.OrderNumber.Caption;
  zqryListExpenseCat.Open;
end;
```

Comment: What does not work in fact? The SQL statement doesn't execute, or you receive an exception in your code? Or results in the SQL database are inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `'` in the line  :

```
zqryInsertExpense.Params[3].Asinteger := zroqryExpcat.FieldByName  (gl_account_no').Value;
```

near  FieldByName( . Are you sure you pasted this code correctly.

Comment: sorry pasted it incorrectly, this routine does not insert the accumulated totals from the main table into the categorized table, but i does work in bds2006, but not with delphi xe2

Comment: You mean the select operation does not return any results in delphi application? Did you try the query directly on db? Any other operations in this delphi xe2 app produce results? Is this the only part of application that doesn't succeed?

Comment: Yes it does not return any results in the delphi app, it i run the select against the db for example in upscenes database workbench i get the resul. This only happens with the application that is compiled with delphi xe2 it works well in delphi 2006